# Linux Device Driver not loaded automatically using udev

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev

I am looking for a way to load my linux device driver automatically on start-up. For that I created a udev rules file:

```
KERNEL=="k1", SUBSYSTEM=="subx", SYMLINK+="sym_subx", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x14ab", ATTRS{device}=="0xe001", MODE="0660", GROUP="xyz"
```

I manually installed the driver first and then restarted the udev. After this, for the first time, I uninstalled and then installed the driver. I could see the driver getting installed correctly and also the symlink being created.

Now when I restart the machine, I am expecting that the driver is loaded automatically on start-up but its not the case. What could be missing here? Is there any entry that I need to do in some .conf file (modprobe.conf or any other)? Where should I put my module.ko file?

I am suspecting that something minor is missing. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Sapan

Comment: how did you "manually install the driver"?

Comment: check `/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules.conf`. `man modules`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to do it myself. Steps to load the driver automatically are:

1. Put module.ko in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/ - You may need to create the "module" directory for the first time
2. Write Udev Rules
3. % sudo depmod -a
   This will update the dependencies of the drivers
4. Check /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep file and search for modules.ko . It should list the dependencies on other modules if any
5. % sudo /sbin/reboot OR sudo udevadm trigger

It worked for me Linux SLES11